# ListItems in CheckboxList text color change

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

Can the color of the text in a listitem in a checkbox list be toggled back and forth with colors on select/deselect?

I am trying to do so with the following code to no avail. ChartstoDisplay is the id of the checkboxlist

```
Protected Sub ChartstoDisplay_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ChartstoDisplay.SelectedIndexChanged
    For i As Integer = 0 To ChartstoDisplay.Items.Count - 1
        If ChartstoDisplay.Items(i).Selected Then
            ChartstoDisplay.Items(i).Attributes.Add("style", "color:DarkGreen;")
        Else
            ChartstoDisplay.Items(i).Attributes.Add("style", """")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: do you absolutely need to do this via code behind or are you willing to do javascript? doing through code behind will make your page seem very jumpy unless this is sitting in an updatepanel... but why do server work when the browser can do it

Comment: Im teaching myself jquery now, an example would be most appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work.  I suspect you just need to add **AutoPostBack="true"** on the CheckBoxList control.  This works for me (using your code-behind):

```
<asp:CheckBoxList AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ChartstoDisplay_SelectedIndexChanged" ID="ChartstoDisplay">
    <!-- Items here -->
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```